# .htaccess redirect domains containing dots

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm using some .htaccess code I found on StackOverflow to redirect non-www domains to their www counterparts:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that this also works for domains on our local development server, and redirects `http://test/` to `http://www.test/`. This is not useful, as the domain `www.test` does not exist on our development server. This means that the .htaccess file used for the site in development needs to be modified when the site goes live.

Is there a simple way to add a line to check that the domain name already has at least one dot? If it contains one dot, continue to add the `www.`. If it doesn't, stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another `RewriteCond` before your `RewriteRule` to exclude your testserver:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test$
```

I think that an explicit exclusion is better than this dot-count thing.

**Edit:** Here is the dot-based version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't work for us. We run many test domains on a bunch of different URLs. Basically, we build a site on our development box before uploading it to a live webserver. The local version will have a dotless domain name; the live version will (of course) have a dotted domain name (usually `.ie` or `.com`).